# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("template.docx")
context = { 'name' :name, 'surname':surname, 'adress':adress,'phonenumber':phonenumber,'marital_status':marital_status,'Date_of_birth':Date_of_birth,'Objective':Objective,'education':education,'qualifications':qualifications,'work_exp':work_exp,'personal_qualities':personal_qualities, 'e_mail':e_mail }
doc.render("context")
doc.save("C:\scripts\CV.docx")
```

При попытке запуска выдаёт ошибку:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is
> required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

замените:

```
doc.render("context")
```

на

```
doc.render(context)
```

вы передаете строковой литерал (строку: `"context"`), вместо ожидаемого словаря.

---

**Причина возникновения данной ошибки:** скорее всего в функции `doc.render()` происходит попытка объединить другой словарь со словарем, переданным в качестве первого аргумента.

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
d = {"a": 1}
d.update("context")
```

выдает:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: Работает, огромное спасибо за помощь, буду вечно помнить )

Answer (score 0):

может так:

```
doc.save("C:\\scripts\\CV.docx")
```

Comment: ctx = self.new_context(dict(*args, **kwargs))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]